# Find by array of IDs and get a sorted response

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of IDs:

```
const arrayIds =
    ['5f43e8ad0500ed0017ff9f65',
    '5f46d26c4dec5600173e60fe',
    '5f47f4a1dae1140017f2a409',
    ...]
```

And I can get all documents using mongoose find:

```
const documents = await Model.find().where('_id').in(arrayIds).exec();
```

But the problem is the response is not sorted. I would like to get an array of documents sorted exactly like arrayIds.

Can you help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: How many elements can be there in array? Is it dynamic?

Comment: @Gibbs my array can be thousands of IDs (from 1000 to 10.000)

The array changes. Think of it like 'products ordered by sales'. The array change with sales.

Thank you.

Comment: You can sort it in the client side. That's the feasible option AFAIK